# OrientDB: can I create an index on a property of type EMBEDDED?

Tags: indexing, orientdb

I have a schema property of type EMBEDDED. When I try to create an index in the web interface for this property, I get a NullPointerException:

```
{"errors":[{"code":500,"reason":500,"content":"com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexException: Cannot create the index 'ORDER.attr_f9e8e581_7076_4b14_a625_37e0e7dbc2a9_2'\r\n\tDB name=\"temp\"\r\n--> java.lang.NullPointerException"}]}
```

Is it even possible to create an index on this type of property? The embedded document has only two properties and I'm not interested in indexing on any embedded property, just the document as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Reading this old response: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/orient-database/OH7hcbSI6E4
it seems forbidden.

Hope it helps.

Regards